# How can I define an AngularJS Typescript output object that's part of a ng.IPromise<{}>?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have this function:

```
getTopics = (params) => {
    var defer = this.$q.defer();
    this.$http({
        cache: this.utilityService.oyc,
        url: '/api/Topic/GetMapData' + params,
        method: "GET"
    })
        .success(function (data: { topicId: number; subTopicId: number; topicName: string; subTopicName; string; }[] ) {
            var output = {
                data: _.chain(data)
                    .uniq(true, 'topicId')
                    .map(function (t) { return { id: t.topicId, name: t.topicName }; })
                    .value(),
                dataMap: _.reduce(data, function (rv, v) {
                    rv[v.subTopicId] = v;
                    return rv;
                }, {}),
                topicNameMap: _.reduce(data, function (rv, v) {
                    rv[v.topicId] = v.topicName;
                    return rv;
                }, {}),
                dataPlus:
                [{ id: 0, name: '*' }].concat(
                    _.chain(data)
                        .uniq(true, 'topicId')
                        .map(function (t) { return { id: t.topicId, name: t.topicName }; })
                        .value())
            };
            defer.resolve(output);
        })
        .error(function () {
            defer.reject();
        });
    return defer.promise;
};
```

When I hover over the function it shows me that it returns a ng.IPromise<{}>

Can someone give me some suggestion of how I can add more information to the object that is returned. I am not so much looking for a complete solution but would just appreciate some tips on how I can define the output for example the `{ data: }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng.IPromise<T>` is generic so the return type can be for example `ng.IPromise<IAnything>`

So you can make your output of type `IAnything`:

```
var output = <IAnything>{
...
};
```

And define your `getTopics` function return value as `ng.IPromise<IAnything>`

Also you would create your defer object like this:

```
var defer = this.$q.defer<IAnything>();
```